# jQueryUI datepicker cutting off year

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to implement a simple datepicker dropdown for my website using the jQueryUI widget, as shown on their website.

The display is fine on Safari and Firefox. On Chrome, however, the selected year gets cut off to the right for some reason. It doesn't seem to be the padding, because as far as I see, the width of the container exceeds the width of the text.

I have tried to overwrite the jQueryUI padding in my css file, I used the !important keyword, and I also made sure to link my stylesheet after linking the jQueryUI stylesheet. It is still not working.

I have also tried to increase the width of my input field, thinking that might be the issue, but I get the same result even if I increase the input width to 100%.

Could anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Here is a screenshot of what is happening: https://ibb.co/Y3064w2

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide the code you are working with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be good to include which Version and of Chrome and the OS you see this in.